# Log shipping setup

Tags: t-sql, logging, log-shipping

Log shipping fails with the below error. Sql agent on secondary server has access to the folder and files in security. It is not a firewall issue. I created the jobs using the LS scripts as it fails through GUI.

I have done it before on a different server where there were several LS databases. This is a new primary and secondary server and not sure what I am missing. Thanks for the help

* Error: Access to the path '\sqlp\R$\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\Database' is denied.(mscorlib) *
----- END OF TRANSACTION LOG COPY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd to set the agent account and sql account of primary server as admin on the secondary server and it worked fine